# regex replace: '[A-Z]'' to [A-Z]' - I can't preserve the letter in in the string

Tags: regex, sed, vi

My google foo is failing me...

I have a file (well over 2 gig's) that has a SQL format problem. So I need a regex that will update the following examples (remember, I don't know how many there are or what the letters are):

1. 'N'' should be changed to N'
2. 'L'' should be changed to L'
   etc

I've tried (within VIM and sed):

```
s/'[A-Z]''/$1'/
```

but that just produces:

```
'N'' -> '$1'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A backreference in sed is  `\1`, not `$1`. You also need to capture the letter using `\(\)` (and probably use the global flag `g`).

Your sed expression should be:

```
s/'\([A-Z]\)''/\1'/g
```

Answer (score 1):

Give this a shot:

```
sed "s/\([[:alpha:]]'\)'/\1/g" file
```

#### Example Output

```
$ sed "s/\([[:alpha:]]'\)'/\1/g" <<<"aBcD''eg''H'i"
aBcD'eg'H'i
```

*Note*: Since you said you didn't know what letters they would be I assumed they could be lower case. If you know for a fact they are always uppercase, then change `[[:alpha:]]` to `[[:upper:]]`. These character classes are preferred over `[A-Za-z]` and `[A-Z]`, respectively, because they will always work as you expect no matter the locale.